# Python run multiple functions same time

Tags: python, multithreading

How can I run each watcher that is set to true inside the watching config, I've tried with threading but that still didnt help. I expect that any watcher set to true should run at the same time even if there are multiple

```
watching_config = {
    "WindowsDefender": False,
    "WindowsFirewall": False
}

def main():
    divider = "-" * 20
    while True:
        clear()

        for char in banner:
            sys.stdout.write(char)
            sys.stdout.flush()
            time.sleep(0.0001)

        print(colors.blue + "\n\n" + divider + " | LogSentry Watching | " + divider + colors.reset)
        print(f"{colors.blue}1. Windows Defender: " + str(watching_config["WindowsDefender"]) + f"{colors.reset}")
        print(f"{colors.blue}2. Windows Firewall: " + str(watching_config["WindowsFirewall"]) + f"{colors.reset}")
        print(f"{colors.blue}3. Start LogSentry{colors.reset}")

        choice = input("\nEnter your choice: ")
        if choice == "1":
            watching_config["WindowsDefender"] = not watching_config["WindowsDefender"]
        elif choice == "2":
            watching_config["WindowsFirewall"] = not watching_config["WindowsFirewall"]
        elif choice == "3":
            for key,value in watching_config.items():
                if value == True:
                    print(f"\n{colors.green}Starting {key} watcher...{colors.reset}")
                    while True:
                        try:
                            # Run the watcher function at the same time
                            # WindowsDefender.Watch() but it will be running at the same time as other watchers
                            else:
                                print(f"{colors.red}Invalid watcher!{colors.reset}")
                                break
                        except KeyboardInterrupt:
                            print(f"{colors.red}{key} watcher was stopped!{colors.reset}")
                            break
```

Here is my attempt with threading:

```
def main():
    divider = "-" * 20
    while True:
        clear()

        for char in banner:
            sys.stdout.write(char)
            sys.stdout.flush()
            time.sleep(0.0001)

        print(colors.blue + "\n\n" + divider + " | LogSentry Watching | " + divider + colors.reset)
        print(f"{colors.blue}1. Windows Defender: " + str(watching_config["WindowsDefender"]) + f"{colors.reset}")
        print(f"{colors.blue}2. Windows Firewall: " + str(watching_config["WindowsFirewall"]) + f"{colors.reset}")
        print(f"{colors.blue}3. Start LogSentry{colors.reset}")

        choice = input("\nEnter your choice: ")
        if choice == "1":
            watching_config["WindowsDefender"] = not watching_config["WindowsDefender"]
        elif choice == "2":
            watching_config["WindowsFirewall"] = not watching_config["WindowsFirewall"]
        elif choice == "3":
            for key,value in watching_config.items():
                if value == True:
                    print(f"\n{colors.green}Starting {key} watcher...{colors.reset}")
                    while True:
                        try:
                            if key == "WindowsDefender":
                                Thread(target=WindowsDefender.Watch).start()
                            elif key == "WindowsFirewall":
                                Thread(target=WindowsFirewall.Watch).start()
                            else:
                                print(f"{colors.red}Invalid watcher!{colors.reset}")
                                break
                        except KeyboardInterrupt:
                            print(f"{colors.red}{key} watcher was stopped!{colors.reset}")
                            break
```

Comment: A good starting point could be here https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#thread-objects, it explains also how to "run" a seperate thread with a specific `function` and arguments for that `function`

Comment: Why not include the code you tried with threading?

Comment: @JonSG https://pastebin.com/raw/eBdSRffZ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There does not seem to be anything wrong with your use of threading at first glance. Perhaps the problem is with the prompting for input and tracking the threads. In any case, here is a quick and dirty example of how I might run two things.

The output gets a little wonky but you can uncomment the print statements to see the workers running.

```py
import multiprocessing
import time
import random

def WindowsDefender_Watch():
    print(f"\tStarting WindowsDefender Watcher...")
    while True:
        #print("\t\tWatching WindowsDefender")
        time.sleep(random.random()*2)

def WindowsFirewall_Watch():
    print(f"\tStarting WindowsFirewall Watcher...")
    while True:
        #print("\t\tWatching WindowsFirewall")
        time.sleep(random.random()*2)

def main():
    procs = []
    while True:
        choice = input("Enter your choice [1|2]: ")
        if choice not in ["1", "2"]:
            break

        target = WindowsDefender_Watch if choice == "1" else WindowsFirewall_Watch
        proc = multiprocessing.Process(target=target)
        proc.start()
        procs.append(proc)
        time.sleep(1)

    for proc in procs:
        proc.terminate()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```